# Issue while inputting korean language in custom textbox control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

While entering the Korean input at the first time ,the letter is first shown in IME window, instead of displaying in the textbox. how to overcome this issue ??? 
Then after pressing the enter in IME window, the letter is displayed in the textbox and also while entering 'rk', it should be displayed as '가' ('가' == 'rk') , but it is displayed as "ㄱㅏ" like this separately. how to overcome this issue, any suggestions please...

Answer (score 0):

The three UNICODE code points you have included in your question are the following:

- 가: Hangul Syllable Ga
- ㄱ: Hangul Letter Kiyeok
- ㅏ: Hangul Letter A

You want the first to display in your UI but instead the second and third are displayed.

The standard font in WPF is Segoe UI and this font does not contain the Ga syllable (가). I am no expert in Hangul but visually it looks like an alternative to writing 가 is to write ㄱㅏ and in Windows the Ga syllable is named Kiyeok A syllable indicating that Ga is created by combining Kiyeok and A. I am pretty sure that 가 is replaced with ㄱㅏ when 가 is absent in the font used.

The solution is to use another font in your UI that contains the desired Hangul syllables. To investigate what characters are present in a font you can use the Windows tool Character Map:

[image: Character Map user interface]